# Spring: Test package naming vs. @EnableAutoConfiguration

Tags: testing, spring-boot

Does anybody know what the convention is for testing a spring-boot application?

Typically java test are organized into package structures which mimic the main package structure:

E.g.

```
src/main/java -> my.application.services -> MyService.java
src/test/java -> my.application.services -> MyServiceTest.java
```

I want my service to be auto-configurable, so I include:

```
src/main/java -> my.application.config -> MyApplicationConfig.java
(includes @ComponentScan("my.application"))
..along with a reference to it in spring.factories
```

I'd like to include configuration for my test.  So I create:

```
src/test/java -> my.application.services -> MyServiceTestConfig.java
(includes @EnableAutoConfiguration)
```

I run test it using:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyServiceTestConfig.class, loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
```

It works well.  Both configuration classes run:

- MyServiceTestConfig directly
- MyApplicationConfig by virtue of @EnableAutoConfiguration

The problem comes when I add a second test:

```
src/main/java -> my.application.services -> MyOtherService.java
src/test/java -> my.application.services -> MyOtherServiceTest.java
src/test/java -> my.application.services -> MyOtherServiceTestConfig.java
```

My issue is that when I run one test, the configuration of the other test is also executed.  E.g. Running MyServiceTest runs all 3 configurations:

- MyServiceTestConfig directly
- MyApplicationConfig by virtue of @EnableAutoConfiguration
- MyOtherServiceTestConfig by virtue of @ComponentScan("my.application")

I can think of several "workarounds" for this issue, but I'd really like to go by-the-book on this one.  Presumably this is an issue with all spring-boot applications?  Is there a generally-accepted practice to follow to avoid it?  Or it there something strange about my setup?

**Edit**

Based on the comments below I think my issue has inadvertently raised this question:

Is it valid for a test to have its own @Configuration (or @Component for that matter)?  If the answer is "no" then it pretty much invalidates my question.

Comment: Why do you need all those configuration, if you want a simply unit test don't use spring boot for it. If you want an integration test, load the context once and reuse.

Comment: I'm writing integration tests.  I'm using the test-specific configuration classes to configure the context for the specific test I'm running.

Comment: Then it isn't an integration but a unit test imho... Then don't use spring boot but mocks. For an integration test use the Spring Boot testing support

Comment: I'll not argue what we call the test.  Essentially my goal is to test that my auto-configurable services all work together to produce the correct behaviour under specified conditions.  You mentioned Spring Boot testing support.  How can I use it to help with the described situation?

Comment: You cannot. How is it that if you configure as single service proof of that your auto configuration works. That you can only test if yu bootstrap the whole context and mock external dependencies or point it to a test database. By only configuring a single service that isn't proof of anything.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing.  I'm using embedded versions of my external dependencies.  E.g. HSQL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105698/discussion-between-andy-n-and-m-deinum).

Comment: And why would that requite a configuration per service and per test? Just add an `application.properties` in your `src/test/resources` in which you override the database and run your tests...

Comment: My configuration isn't anything to do with the database.  I'm using it to configure other behaviour within my app.  In this case I'm using it to configure a messaging service (dependency).  It needs to be configured in different ways for each test.  I haven't included any configurable attributes for it in application.properties.  Continue in chat?